# Can Starcraft run on Mac OS 10.8?

Tags: macos

I wanted to play some Starcraft on my MacBook Pro running Mac OS 10.8. The CD I have has the class Mac OS version. The Mac OS X PowerPC version does not work due to Rosetta being removed (Apple - please don't make this mistake again in Mac OS 11). Is there a way to make Starcraft work on Mac OS 10.8? I would prefer not to use emulators.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this doesn’t belong on this site, dedicated to programming questions.

Comment: Perhaps on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Sorry I think I did ask this question on the wrong site.

Answer (score 0):

Get the OS X patch from here:

https://macintoshgarden.org/games/starcraft

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't see any x86 version of the game there.

Comment: You might need to buy the Starcraft Remastered version. It is only about $15 or you will need to use an emulator.